# How do I use ggspectra()?

Tags: ggplot2, r4photobiology

I would like to use the package [ggspectra](https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2017-02-04/web/packages/ggspectra/vignettes/user-guide.html) but I can't figure out how to use it in means of data type(?). With the examples given with `two_suns.spct` it works, more or less, but when I want to use my own data which is `w.length ~ Intensity/count`, I can't get any plot with it. What do I have to do (with my own data)?

```
df[1:10, ]
    Intensity     w.length
1  0.00021348 1.235582e-21
2  0.00026164 1.008143e-21
3  0.00030980 8.514191e-22
4  0.00035796 7.368669e-22
5  0.00040612 6.494837e-22
6  0.00045428 5.806284e-22
7  0.00050244 5.249731e-22
8  0.00055060 4.790541e-22
9  0.00059876 4.405220e-22
10 0.00064693 4.077270e-22
(...)
```

I'm trying it via:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(photobiology)
library(photobiologyWavebands)
library(ggspectra)

Lambda = h*c / E
h = 6.62607015e-34
c = 299792458
df$w.length = (h * c) / df$Energy_MeV

ggplot(df, aes(x = Energy_MeV, y = Intensity)) + 
  geom_line() +
```

The code line

```
ggplot(df) + geom_line()
```

does not work at all as I receive the information that `aes()` is necessary.

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried and data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten Sure, sorry. Actually, the line which should work is simply "ggplot(df) + geom_line()" but is not working for me. I guess the df needs to be a certain prepared list, or so? But I can't find information about how to do so. According to the examples it is something from the photobiology package but however, I don't know how create an according data structure with just Energy ~ Intensity.

Comment: Where is the `Energy_MeV` column?

Answer (score 1):

'ggspectra' is designed to work with spectral data stored in classes defined in package 'photobiology' as you noticed. These classes are based on data frame but store additional metadata in attributes and have strict expectations about the units used to express the spectral data, the units used to express wavelength and the names of the columns used to store them. This approach has pros and cons. Once we have created an object of one of these classes, when we pass it as argument to `ggplot()`, R dispatches a `ggplot()` method specific to these classes that "know" how to set `aes()` automatically. There are also `autoplot()` methods that build a whole ggplot object. A big advantage of keeping the metadata in attributes of the object were the data is stored is that this ensures their availability not only when plotting but for any other computations now and in the future, helping ensure reproducibility. This of course, requires additional work up front as we need to create an object belonging to a special class and store both data and metadata in it.

When designing these packages I did not expect they would be used for anything other than light and ultraviolet radiation, expressed either as energy in W m-2 or as photons in mol s-1 m-2, and wavelength in nm. Just for completness, I mention that when dealing with these units a data frame con be converted with the conversion constructor `as.source_spct()` into a `source_spct` object if the data are already expressed in the expected units and the column names follow the naming conventions. Alternatively, a `source_spct` object can be created with the `source_spct()` constructor by passing suitable vectors as arguments, similarly to how a data frame is created. Additional arguments can be passed to set the metadata attributes.

Neither of these constructors will work in this case as clearly the spectral data in the question is expressed is some other units or even is a different quantity.